# How can i make sure one word can be surrounded by an element ASP.NET Localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I am translating a string like this and I am wondering if there is a built in functionality so you can highlight a word, so you later can surround a specific word around an element like in the example below

What is shown when users translate

```
Read our Terms of Service here.
```

What is shown on the website

```
Read our Terms of Service <a href="/tos">here</a>.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe doesn't make sense in general, because any given word or phrase in the source language may get translated into a different number of words that may not even be contiguous.

The way this is typically done is that you simply include the markup in your string, and your translators deal with it. Any competent translation service can handle html markup.

Another option is to make the entire sentence the clickable text. The basic principle is to provide complete segments for translation. Attempting to deconstruct or reconstruct from parts is doomed to fail under localization.